# Generating a list of tuples that meet certain criteria without running out of memory

Tags: filtering, memory, permutation, tuples

I would like to generate tuples of length 21 with possible elements 1, 2, and 3. I would also like there to be an equal number of 1's, 2's, and 3's, and I want to control for how many times one element is equal to the element before it in each tuple. That's a bit hard to word, so here is what I've done.

I have my criteria:

```
sieve[combination_] := Count[combination, 1] === Count[combination, 2] === Count[combination, 3] && Count[Table[combination[[i]] == combination[[i + 1]], {i, 1, 20}], False] === 5;
```

Then I generate the tuples:

```
data = Select[Tuples[{1, 2, 3}, {21}], sieve]
```

This works readily for length 9, but for 21 it exhausts my memory. Is there a way I can do this computation?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [Shifrin's lazy tuples](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lshifr/56c6fcfe7cafcd73bdf8/raw/LazyTuples.m).

Comment: Your `sieve` function seems to be hard-wired for the 21-tuple case so it fails for e.g. n=9. Can you make it more general so we can play with ideas? Also, take a look at [`SelectTuples`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SelectTuples) in the Function Repository.

Comment: Do you want a random selection of tuples or all tuples?  If you wanted all of length 21 with 7 1's, 2's, and 3's, then there are 21!/7!^3= 399,072,960 arrangements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

pool = Table[Range[3], 7] // Flatten;
```

Rather than produce all tuples, produce a tuple on demand

```
choice := Module[{ch = RandomSample[pool]},
  While[Count[Most[ch] - Rest[ch], 0] != 15,
   ch = RandomSample[pool]]; ch]

choice

(* {2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2} *)
```

For multiple tuples

```
Table[choice, 5] // Column
```

[image]

Comment: +1 For a length of 21, this clearly makes more sense.

Comment: Brilliant, makes a lot more sense to do it this way. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

For a length of 18 (6 groups of 1, 2, and 3) one finds 17,153,136 permutations.

```
n = 6;
data = Flatten[Table[{1, 2, 3}, {n}]];
p = Permutations[data];
Length[p]
(* 17153136 *)
```

In general for a length of `3 n` there will be `(3 n)!/(n!^3)` permutations.  For `3 n = 21` there will be 399,072,960 permuations.